# Using Firebase Authentication with Go Router and Riverpod

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-riverpod, flutter-go-router

I've been reading through this latest implementation of Go Router with Riverpod but don't know how to use Firebase Authentication Streams with it, and I don't know if I need to be using refreshListenable.

https://github.com/lucavenir/go_router_riverpod/tree/master/complete_example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reading that repo.

I'm hearing the feedback from the community and I will add a Firebase Auth example on top of `complete_example`.

Please raise issues there or contact me on the [ad-hoc discussion](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/discussions/1357) I've if you have requests like this.

Watch the repo for updates (coming soon this week). And possibly, star it (:

Also, PRs are welcome if anything's wrong.

Comment: Hey @tristan-king, here's the updated repo: https://github.com/lucavenir/go_router_riverpod/tree/master/firebase_example